# Efficient way to calculate percentage change based on criteria

Tags: r

What is the most efficient and quickest way to calculate percentage change based on certain criteria? The only way I can think of is using `aggregate` function then loop through each name but I don't think it is efficient.

```
Dataframe 1
2015    Name
538 Johnny Appleseed
14  Johnny Appleseed
40  Johnny Appleseed
524 Johnny Appleseed
10  Sally Smith
50  Jenny Davids (There's no Jenny in 2016)


Dataframe 2
2016    Name
203 Johnny Appleseed
100 Sally Smith
50  Sally Smith
10  Sally Smith
242 Sally Smith
150 Johnny Appleseed
50  Sally Smith
```

[[Update]]
Expected output example

- Johnny Appleseed -68.369%
- Sally Smith 442%
- Jenny Davids N/A

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @RonakShah the percentage change for Johnny Appleseed. I created an output example in the update. Thank you.

Comment: It is still not clear to me. Could you please explain a bit more? How is the percentage calculated ? What is the relation between data frame 1 and 2?

Comment: "Johnny Appleseed" has 4 entires in data frame 1, but only 2 in data frame 2. Do you want to aggregate the values per person and year prior to calculating the percentage change between them? If so, we really need more information.

Comment: @jdobres yes aggregate per person for each year and calculate the percentage. It seems like looping is the only way huh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to accomplish what you're after. My preferred way would be to combine the 2015 and 2016 scores into a single "long" data set. This makes it easier to aggregate and transform data across different categories without loops.

First let's rename the existing columns, since numeric column names can give you problems down the line. We'll also add a "year" column to each data set.

```
colnames(df1) <- c('value', 'name')
colnames(df2) <- c('value', 'name')

df1$year <- 2015
df2$year <- 2016
```

These can now be combined into a single data set:

```
df3 <- rbind(df1, df2)
```

And finally, `dplyr` to the rescue:

```
library(dplyr)
df.change <- group_by(df3, name, year) %>%
             summarize(value = mean(value)) %>%
             ungroup %>% group_by(name) %>%
             summarize(change = (value[year == 2016] - value[year == 2015]) / value[year == 2015])
```

This should produce a data frame with columns for name and percent change.

### Edit: better method that accounts for missing values

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df.change <- group_by(df3, name, year) %>%
             summarize(value = mean(value)) %>%
             ungroup %>%
             spread(year, value) %>%
             mutate(change = (`2016` - `2015`) / `2015`)
```

Comment: okay i was hoping not to use any more packages but I guess this will do. thanks.

Comment: I used to be afraid of using too many packages as well. It felt like "cheating". But R is meant to be expanded beyond its base capabilities, and there's nothing wrong with finding the right tool for the job. `dplyr` is a general-purpose data manipulation package that can serve you well in a huge number of situations.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine this would be faster than looping:

```
library(dplyr)

year_2015 <- c(538, 14, 40, 524, 10, 50)
name <- c("Johnny Appleseed", "Johnny Appleseed", "Johnny Appleseed", "Johnny Appleseed", "Sally Smith", "Jenny Davids")
df1 = data.frame(year_2015, name)

year_2016 <- c(203, 100, 50, 10, 242, 150, 50)
name <- c("Johnny Appleseed", "Sally Smith", "Sally Smith", "Sally Smith", "Sally Smith", "Johnny Appleseed", "Sally Smith")
df2 <- data.frame(year_2016, name)


df1 <- data.frame(summarize(group_by(df1, name),
             sum_year_2015 = sum(year_2015)))

df2 <- data.frame(summarize(group_by(df2, name),
             sum_year_2016 = sum(year_2016)))

data <- merge(df1, df2, by.x="name", by.y="name", all.x=TRUE)
data$name <- as.character(data$name)

final <- data.frame(cbind(data$name, (data$sum_year_2016 - data$sum_year_2015)/data$sum_year_2015))
names(final) <- c("name", "percentage_change")
final
```

Answer (score 0):

The dplyr only method is indeed more efficient however the currently accepted answer doesn't work. Corrected version of @jdobres method is within fun1:

```
library(dplyr)
#make df1
value <- c(538, 14, 40, 524, 10, 50)
name <- c("Johnny Appleseed", "Johnny Appleseed", "Johnny Appleseed", "Johnny Appleseed", "Sally Smith", "Jenny Davids")
df1 = data.frame(value, name)
#make df2
value <- c(203, 100, 50, 10, 242, 150, 50)
name <- c("Johnny Appleseed", "Sally Smith", "Sally Smith", "Sally Smith", "Sally Smith", "Johnny Appleseed", "Sally Smith")
df2 <- data.frame(value, name)
#dplyr only method by jdobres
fun1 <- function(df1, df2) {
  df1$year <- 2015
  df2$year <- 2016
  df3 <- rbind(df1, df2)
  df.change <- group_by(df3, name, year) %>%
            summarize(total = sum(value)) %>%
            summarize(change = (total[year==2016] - total[year==2015])/total[year==2015])
}
benchmark(fun1(df1, df2), replications=100000)
#             test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
# 1 fun1(df1, df2)       100000 162.747        1   159.873     1.15          0         0


library(dplyr)
library(rbenchmark)
#make df1
year_2015 <- c(538, 14, 40, 524, 10, 50)
name <- c("Johnny Appleseed", "Johnny Appleseed", "Johnny Appleseed", "Johnny Appleseed", "Sally Smith", "Jenny Davids")
df1 = data.frame(year_2015, name)
#make df2
year_2016 <- c(203, 100, 50, 10, 242, 150, 50)
name <- c("Johnny Appleseed", "Sally Smith", "Sally Smith", "Sally Smith", "Sally Smith", "Johnny Appleseed", "Sally Smith")
df2 <- data.frame(year_2016, name)
#function to test with dplyr and merge
fun2 <- function(df1, df2) {
   df1 <- data.frame(summarize(group_by(df1, name),
   sum_year_2015 = sum(year_2015)))
   df2 <- data.frame(summarize(group_by(df2, name),
   sum_year_2016 = sum(year_2016)))
   data <- merge(df1, df2, by.x="name", by.y="name", all.x=TRUE)
   data$name <- as.character(data$name)
   final <- data.frame(cbind(data$name, (data$sum_year_2016 - data$sum_year_2015)/data$sum_year_2015))
}
benchmark(fun2(df1, df2), replications=100000)
#             test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
# 1 fun2(df1, df2)       100000 251.466        1    245.11    2.168          0         0
```

Comment: Well, this is what I get for trying to write code without a working data set. :)